# using setter to inject service into Enum...Bad Practice?

Tags: java, spring, enums

Is this considered bad practice? Essentially, based on the enum I want to call a specific method in an interface. Each enum will have its own interface implementation (WalkImpl,RunImpl,JogIMpl, etc....) all based off of the ActivityService interface. I just wanted to know is this the right way to "inject" a service into an Enum. I am doing it this way since I can't autowire the service. Thanks

```
@Component
public class HelloWorldImpl implements HelloWorld {

private enum MyEnum{

    WALK {
        @Override
         public void execute() {
            System.out.println("I am walking");
            activityService.doSomethingWithMe(this.name());
        }
    },
    RUN{
        @Override
        public void execute() {
            System.out.println("I am running");
        }
    },JOG{
        @Override
        public void execute() {
            System.out.println("I am jogging!");
        }
    }, SKIP{
        @Override
        public void execute() {
            System.out.println("I am skipping!");
        }
    };

    public abstract void execute();

    private static ActivityService activityService;

    public void setActivityService(ActivityService activityService) {
        this.activityService = activityService;
    }
}


@Autowired
ActivityService activityService;


 @Override
 public void executeMe(){
    MyEnum myEnum = MyEnum.WALK;
    myEnum.setActivityService(activityService);
    myEnum.execute();

  }
}
```

Comment: It's hard to say exactly without understanding the actual task you're trying to accomplish. I'd say that using an enum for this kind of job is usually using the wrong tool for the job, especially with Spring component scanning; I usually prefer a Command object pattern with the implementations injected into a holder/dispatcher.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enums are best used for things that MUST be differentiated in code--business logic.  If you are using them for data (as your example), it doesn't make any sense to me.

Also, by data vs code I'm not talking about simply iterating over them, you actually have to have significantly different code USING different enums, otherwise they are just a (bad) data initialization device.

A better initialization of that type of data might be:

```
String[] init=new String[] {"WALK", "I am walking", "SKIP", "I am skipping", ...}
Map lookup=new HashMap();
for(int i=0;i+=2;i<init.length)
{
    lookup.put(init[i],init[i+1])
}
```

No redundancy, much simpler, and when that list becomes more complicated it's trivial to take it outside of the code to a text, properties, xml or whatever flavor of data you prefer.

You can even associate code with these if that is what you are after by wrapping "Lookup" and this entire initialization into an object (A good idea)  I'd make something that looked like this:

```
public class Motivate() 
{

    private static Map<String, Motivate> motivations;
    private String action;
    private String description;

    private Motivate(String action, String description)
    {
        this.action=action;
        this.description=description;
    }
    public void init()
    {
        if(motivations == null)
        {
            build motivations using all the stuff in the first example
        }
    }
}
```

If you want different code attached (assuming your examples were just trivial and each "Mode" needed different code), add a member that holds an interface like "Runnable" and pass that into the constructor when you build them.

Then your code should never refer to "RUN" or "WALK", it is just data that is bound, for instance, to a users keystroke or some other data.

Comment: I was using the switch in the executeme method but I read you shouldn't use enums in a switch. This was the only alternative I could think of. I think using a switch in the executeme method is a better approach. The mode was exactly what I was after. Depending on the mode different methods would be called in the interface.

Comment: Simply using a switch (or an if/then/else pattern that works like a switch) is a "Bad code smell"--more accurately it's an OO anti-pattern.  The solutions generally involve each case being a different sub-class or simply using a map that maps a key (whatever you are comparing in your switch) to some code (like a Runnable).  Although at first this doesn't seem to save you much, once you get in the habit of coding without switches a lot of other refactorings become possible that couldn't have been done otherwise.

Answer (score 5):

Do not use enums like that. When I have more time I will explain but most programmers expect and even Java the language somewhat expects enums to be idempotent and immutable.

All member variables in an enum should be final and an enum should not produce side effects. This is because enums are a form (albeit crappy) of functional programming style dispatch. That is enums should be treated as symbols and not objects (even though they are singleton objects).

Also do not use enums to solve the singleton pattern unless you are following the functional rules from above. Here is how I would probably right your given code:

```
@Component
public class HelloWorldImpl implements HelloWorld {

    private enum MyEnum{
        //Notice the final here 
        private final String message;
        WALK ("I am walking"),
        RUN("I am running"),
        JOG("I am jogging!"),
        SKIP("I am skipping!");

        public MyEnum(String message) { this.message = message; }

        public String getMessage() { return this.message; }

    }        

    @Autowired
    ActivityService activityService;

    @Override
    public void executeMe() {
       MyEnum myEnum = MyEnum.WALK;
       _executeMe(myEnum);
    }

    void _executeMe(MyEnum m) {
        //switch or if on the enums you want to 
        //do stuff on with the activity service.
        System.out.println(m.getMessage());
        if (m == MyEnum.WALK)
           activityService.doSomethingWithMe(m.name());
    }
}
```