# Enum Switch to handle interface method calls..bad practice?

Tags: java, spring, enums

I asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21372045/using-setter-to-inject-service-into-enum-bad-practice) but I thought maybe this should be a separate question. Given the following class. Is this the best way to handle interface specific method calls based on a enum type? Thanks

```
@Component
public class HelloWorldImpl implements HelloWorld {

private enum MyEnum{

WALK,RUN,JOG,SKIP

}


@Autowired
@Qualifier("walkService")
private ActivityService walkService;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("runService")
private ActivityService runService;

@Override
public void executeMe(){
 MyEnum myEnum = MyEnum.WALK;

  for(MyEnum enum : MyEnum.values()){
    switch(enum){
     case RUN:
        runService.execute();
     case WALK : 
       walkService.execute();
     etc....
    }   
  }
 }
}
```

I was trying to determine if there was a way I could just use the interface (i.e. ActivityService) to call the execute method instead of being specific to the "MODE" (i.e. switch / if). I was just thinking about what happens if I add a new "MODE" I will have to remember to add a section to this switch statement. Any help is greatly appreciated.

*Update
This exact pattern is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19231875/choose-which-implementation-to-inject-at-runtime-spring).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt you can make it any better. Well, you could by using the [Factory](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternFactory.aspx) pattern, but that seems to be overkill here.

Take a look at : http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Calendar.java#Calendar.getInstance%28java.util.Locale%29

They use If statements in there. Seems like your code goes one better.

```
In order to evolve code in a factory scenario :
a) Caller has to know something about the "kind" of concrete implementation needed
b) For each "kind" of service a subclass is needed
```

Perhaps the only thing to criticize in your implementation is that the "kind" is hidden by a HelloWorldImpl that "knows" which service to return. Its probably more explicit to use subclasses directly because the method "executeMe" says nothing about what kind of service will be chosen at runtime (it depends on the enum).

Comment: I think this is the answer. I don't think there is really anything you can do better. I will hold off on marking yours as the answer until I see if other ideas come.

Answer (score 2):

You'd better add a method to the enum itself:

```
private enum MyEnum {
    WALK {
        @Override
        public void execute() {
            ...
        }
    },
    RUN {
        @Override
        public void execute() {
            ...
        }
    }

    public abstract void execute();
}
```

That way, there(s no way you can add a new enum value without implementing its associated `execute()` method.

And the method becomes:

```
public void executeMe(){
    MyEnum myEnum = MyEnum.WALK;
    myEnum.execute();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do this because I need access to the service implementation. Please see the linked question.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need such `switch` statement :)

```
@Override
public void executeMe(){
     runService.execute();
}
```

All you need to is just call method on the interface. And JVM will run whichever implementation is already assigned to your `service` variable. That is the beauty of interfaces and exact reason they exist for.

Comment: Agreed but each service implementation would need to be injected via a constructor to a wrapper class, if I chose this route. I thought that would be overkill.

Comment: I believe typical injection frameworks select the specific implementation of the interface once at bean creation time. This allows one specific implementation of the same behavior to be chosen (analogy would be - choose the best implementation of a search algorithm but not vary it while program executes) : http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/injection.html. However OP wants to be able to select different services (walk, run, jog) at runtime based on some discriminator that the caller holds.

Comment: If at runtime, then you're correct, my answer isn't the solution here.

Answer (score 1):

Define a mapping of enumKey => concreteActivityServiceBean;
something like this in your spring app context:

```
<util:map id="activityServiceMapping" key-type="java.lang.String" value-type="com.somePackage.ActivityService" map-class="java.util.HashMap">
        <entry key="RUN" value-ref="runServiceImpl" />
        <entry key="WALK" value-ref="walkServiceImpl" />
</util:map>

@Component("runServiceImpl")
class RunServiceImpl implements ActivityService { 
 @Override
 public void execute(){ ... }
}

@Component("walkServiceImpl")
class WalkServiceImpl implements ActivityService { 
 @Override
 public void execute(){ ... }
}
```

And conditionally select the implementation to execute:

```
@Component
class HelloWorldImpl implements HelloWorld {

    @Resource(name = "activityServiceMapping")
    private Map<String, ActivityService> activityServices;

    @Override
    public void executeMe() {
        ActivityService activityService = activityServices.get("WALK"); // or "RUN" or use the ENUM values....
        activityService.execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: Good suggestion but I don't think it will work in this scenario. Thanks Zaki

Comment: I believe the same type of code - having a Map<Enum,ActivityService> could also be done in HelloWorldImpl. However your suggestion does have the advantage of externalizing the relation between the enum types to the service Impls.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to refactor your class, so you only need one instance of the `ActivityService` class. Your code would then look something like this:

```
@Component
public class HelloWorldImpl implements HelloWorld {

    private enum MyEnum{

    WALK,RUN,JOG,SKIP

    }    

    @Autowired
    private ActivityService activityService;        

    @Override
    public void executeMe(){
        MyEnum myEnum = MyEnum.WALK;
        activityService.execute(myEnum);

     }
}
```

But it is hard to say whether this is a viable option, without knowing more about the responsibilities of `ActivityService`.

Comment: I don't think I can refactor because each "service" handles something very specific to that mode.

Comment: doesnt this "activityService.execute(myEnum)" just delegate the switching behavior to activityService.

Comment: @algorithmic: You are correct that in my simple example, the switching is simply delegated. My primary point, however, was that it seems to me that a large part of the point in having an interface is that the caller does not care about the implementation, and it therefore seems like a code smell to have multiple instances of the same interface to choose from. Your answer also adresses this, and in a cleaner way, by seperating the responsibility for switching into a factory. But if not using a factory, I would rather have the switch in the service than in the caller.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you really just want the runner class to execute on the correct type every time without using DI or any class selection code or ifs or switch, then ensure that the correct class is instantiated prior to executing it.

```
ActionExecutor actionExecutor = (ActionExecutor)Class.forName("com.package.name." + action.name()).newInstance();

actionExecutor.execute();
```

Voila! Problem solved as long as you have a class for every possible action and those classes have a default constructor.

Comment: `Class.forName("com.package.name." + action.name()).newInstance();` creates a new instance of a class and this will not be known to Spring and anything that is `@Autowired` will be initialized as null since the instance was not created by Spring

Comment: There is a way to initialize Spring injections in a class instance created via a call to new.  It is rarely used and rarely mentioned, but I have used it successfully in the past.  Unfortunately, I can't remember the name of the method, I just know there is one - you essentially pass the new instance to a Spring method that is able to populate injected values.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced a similar problem. I found a solution that is more generic that the accepted answer.

The first step is to create an Interface.

```
public interface ActivityExecutor {
     public void execute();
}
```

Now, all the required classes to execute must implement this class

```
public class WalkExecutor implements ActivityExecutor  {

     @Autowired
     private WalkService walkService;

     public void execute(){
         walkService.execute();
     }
}


public class RunExecutor implements ActivityExecutor  {

     @Autowired
     private RunService runService;

     public void execute(){
         runService.execute();
     }
}
```

Now the enums are declared in the following way

```
private enum MyEnum {
    WALK {
        @Override
        public String getClassName() {
            return "com.basepackage.WalkExecutor";
        }
    },
    RUN {
        @Override
        public String getClassName() {
            return "com.basepackage.RunExecutor";
        }
    }

    public abstract String getClassName();
}
```

In the processing part, do the following.

```
String className = MyEnum.WALK.getClassName();
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(className);
private static ApplicationContext appContext;
ActivityExecutor activityExecutor = (ActivityExecutor) appContext.getBean(clazz);
activityExecutor.execute(); // executes the required Service
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of fixing this problem could be:

```
public enum ExecutorType {
    WALK, RUN
}
```

```
interface Executor {
    void execute();
    ExecutorType type();
}
```

Here we are able to do DI and create CDI/Spring Bean

```
final class WalkExecutor implements Executor {
    @Override
    public void execute() {
        /** some logic **/
    }
    
    @Override
    public ExecutorType type() {
        return ExecutorType.WALK;
    }
}
```

then we can access valid executor for given type.

```
public final class ExecutorService {
    private final Map<ExecutorType, Executor> executorMap;

    ExecutorService(List<Executor> executors) {
        this.executorMap = executors.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Executor::type), Function.identity()));
    }
    
    public void execute(ExecutorType type) {
        executorMap.get(type).execute();
    }
}
```

Additionally we can ensure that every Executor type is implemented using either integration test or configuration class.

Configuration class using Spring:

```
@Configuration
class ExecutorConfiguration {

    /** other beans definition **/

    @Bean
    ExecutorService executorService(List<Executor> executors) {
        if (!allExecutorsImplemented(executors)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Invalid executor configuration");
        }
        return new ExecutorService(executors);
    }

    private boolean allExecutorsImplemented(List<Executor> executors) {
        return executors.stream().map(Executor::type).distinct().count() == ExecutorType.values().length;
    }
}
```